# How to change date fields to first day of the week - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have column Date_added as date type and I want to change it to first day of the week (Monday)...
for example

input:

```
2018/07/19
2018/06/20
2018/06/21
2018/05/15
etc...
```

output:

```
2018/07/16
2018/06/18
2018/06/18
2018/05/14
etc...
```

I have a thousands of records, so how do I do it...with DATEADD or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use `DATEADD()` in Oracle.  It doesn't exist.  You can use `NEXT_DAY()`:

```
select next_day(datecol - 7, 'Monday')
```

`NEXT_DAY()` gets the next date with that day of the week.

Comment: @Shade888 This will only change the day/month to Monday it will not change the time component of the date.

Comment: I am only interested in that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to truncate the date to the start of the ISO week (midnight Monday) then:

```
SELECT TRUNC( date_column, 'IW' )
FROM your_table;
```

If you want to have the same time component then you can use:

```
NEXT_DAY( date_column - 7, 'MONDAY' )
```

However, if the date language does not match then you will get an exception:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH'

SELECT date_column,
       NEXT_DAY( date_column - 7, 'MONDAY' )
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

```
ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week
```

Alternatively, you can use a language independent method:

```
date_column - ( TRUNC( date_column ) - TRUNC( date_column, 'IW' ) )
```

For example:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b654c/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( date_column ) AS
  SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT date_column,
       TRUNC( date_column, 'IW' ) AS monday_midnight,
       date_column - ( TRUNC( date_column ) - TRUNC( date_column, 'IW' ) ) AS monday_with_time
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b654c/7/0)**:

```
|          DATE_COLUMN |      MONDAY_MIDNIGHT |     MONDAY_WITH_TIME |
|----------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2018-07-16T22:17:22Z | 2018-07-16T00:00:00Z | 2018-07-16T22:17:22Z |
| 2018-07-16T00:00:00Z | 2018-07-16T00:00:00Z | 2018-07-16T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: This would be very helpful in some cases. Thank you for you detailed and well explained answer.